# Joomla is there a way use the data from component to another?

Tags: joomla2.5

I am trying to use the contact data from one component on another. Is there a way that I can do this? If so can someone lead me in the right direction.

Comment: What is "contact data"? Is it stored in the database?

Answer (score 0):

yes... you might have to import their respective libraries / objects / models /ect into the code your're working in with:

```
require_once(''):
```

or joomla's

```
jimport('joomla.application.component.controller');
```

see

```
http://docs.joomla.org/Jimport
```